# Alarm Application Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, alarm

So I'm making simple alarm clock for my project at university. I'm using Android Studio.

Here's the code:

```
public class AlarmActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TimePicker alarm_timer;
TextView update_text;
Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm);
    this.context = this;

    // initialize
    alarm_timer = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
    update_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    //create instance of calendar
    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    Button alarm_on = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bttnAlarmSet);

    //onClickListener
    assert alarm_on != null;
    alarm_on.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)  
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarm_timer.getHour()); 
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, alarm_timer.getMinute());

            int hour = alarm_timer.getHour();
            int minute = alarm_timer.getMinute();

            //convert int values to string
            String hour_string = String.valueOf(hour);
            String minute_string = String.valueOf(minute);

            //Change TextView
            set_alarm_text("Alarm set to: "+ hour_string +":"+ minute_string );
    }
    });        
}

//Method to Change text View
private void set_alarm_text(String output) {
     update_text.setText(output);
}
```

If i set it up without calendar.set(...) and hour_string/minute_string, to just display alarm set it works perfectly, else the app stops working.

Project Structure is for API19: Android 4.4(KitKat). My phone is API23: Android 5.1(Lollipop).

When I wrote

```
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarm_timer.getHour()); 
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, alarm_timer.getMinute());
```

It says "Call requires API Level 23 (Current min is 19)". And from the little yellow bulbm it automaticly wrote me the line "@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)  ". I think this is where the problem is, but I'm bad at Java or anything Java-related.

If anyone could help me or at least notice any mistake, I would be gratefull!

Comment: The error message is pretty straight forward: remove the line that starts with `@TargetApi...` and try again...

Comment: "Call requires API Level 23 (Current min is 19)".  means , that line of code you have used is developed and supported in new android-os.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the TimePicker class. The methods `getHour()` and `getMinute()` you use [have been added in API level 23](https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/23/changes/android.widget.TimePicker.html).

You have to use other methods or you have to implement two versions, one for API23 and one for lower versions.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the getHour() and getMinute() method by getCurrentHour() and getCurrentMinute() methods.